# How to consume a Jax-RS 2.0 Response from Mule Apikit

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, mule, jersey-client

I am trying to consume a JAX-RS 2 Response with Jersey client 2.17.

```
Response response = ClientBuilder.newClient()
                    .target("http://localhost:8080/api")
                    .path("organisations")
                    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .get(); //[1] .get(GetOrganisationsResponse.class);
//[2] System.out.println("headers=" + response.getHeaders());
//[3] String json = response.readEntity(String.class);
//[4] System.out.println("json=" + json);
Organisations orgs = response.readEntity(Organisations.class);
```

The response is served by [Mule apikit](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/APIkit).

```
<flow name="get:/organisations:my-api-config" >
    <set-payload value="#[app.registry['organisations'].getOrganisations(message.inboundProperties['start'], message.inboundProperties['pages'])]" doc:name="Set Payload" />
</flow>
```

POJOs are generated from a RAML description. Here is the generated POJO for the above service:

```
/**
 * A collection of organisations
 * 
 */
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "size",
    "organisations"
})
public class Organisations {

/**
 * 
 * (Required)
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("size")
private Integer size;
@JsonProperty("organisations")
private List<Organisation> organisations = new ArrayList<Organisation>();
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
 * 
 * (Required)
 * 
 * @return
 *     The size
 */
@JsonProperty("size")
public Integer getSize() {
    return size;
}

/**
 * 
 * (Required)
 * 
 * @param size
 *     The size
 */
@JsonProperty("size")
public void setSize(Integer size) {
    this.size = size;
}

public Organisations withSize(Integer size) {
    this.size = size;
    return this;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The organisations
 */
@JsonProperty("organisations")
public List<Organisation> getOrganisations() {
    return organisations;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param organisations
 *     The organisations
 */
@JsonProperty("organisations")
public void setOrganisations(List<Organisation> organisations) {
    this.organisations = organisations;
}

public Organisations withOrganisations(List<Organisation> organisations) {
    this.organisations = organisations;
    return this;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

public Organisations withAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    return this;
}
}
```

... and here is the generated `GetOrganisationsResponse` for the same service:

```
public class GetOrganisationsResponse
    extends support.ResponseWrapper
{


    private GetOrganisationsResponse(Response delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    /**
     * OK
     * 
     * @param entity
     *     
     */
    public static Organisations.GetOrganisationsResponse withJsonOK(model.Organisations entity) {
        Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.status(200).header("Content-Type", "application/json");
        responseBuilder.entity(entity);
        return new Organisations.GetOrganisationsResponse(responseBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

In trying to GET an instance of `Organisations` on the client side, I observed the following:

- All the properties from `Organisations` end up populated in the `additionalProperties` member suggesting none were recognized by the parser,
- If I comment out the additionalProperties member and getter/setter, the parser's error is this:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "date" (class model.Organisations), not marked as
>   ignorable (2 known properties: "size", "organisations"])

- ... this makes sense if the date, headers (and others) fields were not mapped to the Response, but to the Organisations instead but why?
- when uncommenting the lines marked 2, 3 and 4, the Response converted to String looks as follows. Shouldn't the `GetOrganisationsResponse` headers have been parsed and returned as a result of `response.getHeaders()` ?

> headers={X-MULE_ENCODING=[UTF-8], Date=[Mon, 30 Mar 2015 02:16:57
>   +0000], Content-Length=[746], X-MULE_SESSION=[...], Connection=[close], http.status=[200],
>   Content-Type=[application/json], Server=[Mule Core/3.6.1]}
>       json={"date":null,"lastModified":null,"headers":{"Content-Type":["application/json"]},"entity":{"size":3,"organisations":[{"oid":"54df33936d725e370b000004","name":"org1","additionalProperties":{}},{"oid":"54df34406d725e370b000006","name":"org2","additionalProperties":{}},{"oid":"54df33c96d725e370b000005","name":"org3","additionalProperties":{}}],"additionalProperties":{}},"status":200,"mediaType":{"type":"application","subtype":"json","parameters":{},"wildcardType":false,"wildcardSubtype":false},"allowedMethods":[],"links":[],"cookies":{},"entityTag":null,"statusInfo":"OK","metadata":{"Content-Type":["application/json"]},"stringHeaders":{"Content-Type":["application/json"]},"length":-1,"language":null,"location":null}

- Finally when trying to force the Response as generated on the server side with `.get(GetOrganisationsResponse.class)` (uncommenting 1), the outcome is:

> Can not find a deserializer for non-concrete Map type [map type; class
>   javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String]
>   -> [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class java.lang.String]]]

- The culprit is the following code in the parent class of `GetOrganisationResponse` called `ResponseWrapper`:

  @Override
  public MultivaluedMap getHeaders()
  {
      return delegate.getHeaders();
  }

  @Override
  public MultivaluedMap getStringHeaders()
  {
      return delegate.getStringHeaders();
  }

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction:

1. Is `client.get()` or `client.get(GetOrganisationsResponse.class)` the recommended aproach to parse a Mule Apikit response on the client? (I could not find answers in Mule docs)
2. Considering I get errors for either option: Thanks for your help&ideas on how to fix them.

Comment: You have "ignore nulls" but the fields are still unknown as they don't exist in the class. You can add the annotation to to the class `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` to ignore the `date` and such, which you don't have as fields

Comment: I get your point but the unknown fields are from generated `GetOrganisationsResponse` and its parent `ResponseWrapper`.My understanding is that they were meant to be mapped to `Response` as `Response.getDate`, `Response.getHeaders` , not to my pojo which is at `Response.getEntity`

Comment: Can you print out `readEntity(String.class)` and see what it prints out. Printing out the entire response doesn't help. I would imagine that string will have the `date` fields, as well as others, in the JSON. When you print out the entire response object, I would image the `json=` is the entire body

Comment: If that it the case, it seems the `entity` object in the JSON is what you want. I don't know if MULE has any API to extract it, but to do it manually, you can use the `ObjectMapper` explicitly or wrapper the `Organizations` in a wrapper with all the keys from the response or just have the entity field with the ignore annotation mentioned above.